# Pattern returning pseudo random number generator

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, random

**Edit:**

Due to the responses of so many having no idea of what I was asking, I've rephrased the question.

```
extern unsigned short lfsr();
int foo[65536];
for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++)
    foo[lfsr()] = 1;
// every element of foo has been set to 1.
```

I want source code for `lfsr()` which returns a pseudo random 16 bit value, 0 to 65535. If called 65536 times it will have returned every number from 0 to 65535 exactly once, with no repetition. If you did it again, it would return the same sequence. Not a great random number generator but it has its uses.

I once had code for this from a Dr. Dobbs Journal of Computer Calisthenics and Orthodontia around 1984.

This seems very similar to a noise generator but the exception is that the cycle repeats and that would not work for audio. Rendering the same 64K 16 bit PCM samples would be noticeably repetitive in less than 1.5 seconds at 48 kHz, and I've never heard that from a 16 bit noise generator.

Note:
A shuffle method wouldn't have worked in 1984 as the array would take 128K which would have been more than twice the available memory on an Apple][ or similar computer.

**Answer:**
Thanks to Jesper Juhl and Jim Mischel for identifying it as an LFSR, linear feedback shift register and where to find the original article.

Sorry for the poorly phrased original question and thanks for your time.

Comment: I read your question a few times but I couldn't understand what you want. Do you want a way to generate random numbers? Or do you want a way to generate pink noise (1/f noise)?

Comment: Question begging for code get close voted as off-topic pretty fast here.You should [edit] your question to remove those parts.

Comment: Punch "hasty pudding" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: A really easy way to do this, although it would require some memory, is to create an array of the numbers from 0 to 65,535, and then [shuffle them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: By the way, if you're interested in finding the article, the table of contents for DDJ 1980 editions is at ftp://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/toc/dr-dobbs-1980.html.

Comment: Also relevant: https://www.schneier.com/academic/archives/1994/09/pseudo-random_sequen.html

Comment: @JimMischel I'll definitely be going through those archives. It would be nice to see the original code. I don't even remember what language or processor the code was written for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for is a [linear-feedback shift register](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register). It can have the properties you seem to want of returning the full sequence in seemingly random order without repeating an element of the range.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for and thanks for understanding the original post.